# Insert blank lines between git add --patch prompts

Tags: git, configuration

Whenever I use `git add --patch` and answer one prompt, it prints the second diff and prompt immediately after. This makes it very difficult for me to quickly scan to the beginning of the current prompt - it's easy to miss the tiny message from the previous prompt and confuse the boundary.

Is there a way I can make git add some kind of separator, such as `--------`, before printing each subsequent prompt?

Comment: Currently, the `--patch` functionality of `git add`, `git reset`, and other commands is implemented as a Perl script. This makes it really easy to hack on: just copy the existing Perl script from its exec path (run `git --exec-path` to see where that is; look in the resulting directory for `git-add--interactive`; that's the Perl script). Edit your copy and run that, and you get your new functionality.

Comment: Note that if you get this working the way you want, you should consider submitting a patch to the Git mailing list. There is a project to convert all this stuff to C programs; you'd want your fixes / improvements to go in before this gets finished!